# Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA in a cross database query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 6 variables that is: `@SourceDatabase, @SourceSchema, @SourceTable, @TargetDatabase, @TargetSchema, @TargetTable`

Im writing a query that should join values from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. 
Like this:

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME, b.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA b
ON b.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SourceSchema
AND b.TABLE_NAME = @SourceTable
AND b.COLUMN_NAME = a.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE a.TABLE_SCHEMA = @TargetSchema
AND a.TABLE_NAME = @TargetTable
```

However, after I introduced the database-attributes, to do comparison cross databases, i just noticed that i dont think i can use the same query without making it dynamic as a String and putting databasename in front of INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Like `DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(254) = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @SourceDatabase + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA ...'`. etc etc

Since im not really a fan of doing dynamic sql, im wondering if you guys have any clever solutions to do what im trying to do without going dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is certainly the easiest way to handle this kind of thing, but you are certain this is not an option?

The only other alternative I can think of is to UNION ALL on all of your databases, with an additional db name column:

```
SELECT 'db1' AS dbName, *
FROM db1.sys.columns
UNION ALL
SELECT 'db2' AS dbName, *
FROM db2.sys.columns
```

The collation needs to be the same in both databases. But Dynamic SQL would be easier, and could be made to work for *any* database, rather than just those in your union list.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is a real and doable option. And i certainly like it better than doing union all on all databases since i need it to work for any database. It need to work even if databases are removed or added. And it should work on any server.

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe there is a view or table that contains all columns regardless of database? And i could query this view instead of the database-specific information_schema

Comment: There is an undocumented stored procedure called sp_msforeachdb (which could be used like sp_msforeachdb 'select "?" AS db, * from [?].sys.columns'), but this may be a "bad" thing to use. Dynamic SQL would certainly be a far more accepted method.

Comment: Yeah i agree. Thanks for your comments and ideas Miika! I'll keep the question open for a day more to see if someone knows something we dont. If not i'll mark your answer as correct. Cheers mate!